# How do I force a square layout on my AbsoluteLayout?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Anyone know why the following code doesn't execute the OnMeasure() in my Forms app?? I'm basically trying to force an AbsoluteLayout to have the same height/width to show up as a Square:

```
public class AbsoluteSquareLayout : AbsoluteLayout
{
    protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        var size = Math.Min(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
        return base.OnMeasure(size, size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overriding size constraints in `OnMeasure` call doesn't guarantee final size - as the final `Layout` pass from parent layout will override this value. XF article [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom/#Layout) talks about this in detail.

In order to be able to achieve a square layout - you will have to update the parent layout to consider those constraints, and ensure it is passed in layout pass.

For example you can extend `AbsoluteLayout` to dynamically calculate the size constraints for children. This custom layout treats all children as squares by default. In order to override that behavior for a particular child - you can set attached property `SquareLayout.IsSquare` as `false`.

```
public class SquareLayout : AbsoluteLayout
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsSquareProperty = 
          BindableProperty.CreateAttached("IsSquare",
                                          typeof(bool),
                                          typeof(SquareLayout),
                                          defaultValue: true,
                                          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public static bool GetIsSquare(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (bool)view.GetValue(IsSquareProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsSquare(BindableObject view, bool value)
    {
        view.SetValue(IsSquareProperty, value);
    }

    Dictionary<View, Rectangle> _boundsCache = new Dictionary<View, Rectangle>();
    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        foreach(var child in Children)
        {
            var isSquare = GetIsSquare(child);
            if(isSquare)
            {
                Rectangle bounds;
                if (!_boundsCache.ContainsKey(child))
                    _boundsCache[child] = bounds = GetLayoutBounds(child);
                else
                    bounds = _boundsCache[child];

                var absFlags = GetLayoutFlags(child);

                var widthIsProportional = (absFlags & AbsoluteLayoutFlags.WidthProportional) != 0;
                var heightIsProportional = (absFlags & AbsoluteLayoutFlags.HeightProportional) != 0;

                var childWidth = widthIsProportional ? bounds.Width * width : bounds.Width;
                var childHeight = heightIsProportional ? bounds.Height * height : bounds.Height;

                var size = Math.Min(childWidth, childHeight);

                SetLayoutBounds(
                    child,
                    new Rectangle(
                        bounds.X,
                        bounds.Y,
                        (widthIsProportional ? (size / width) : size),
                        (heightIsProportional ? (size / height) : size)
                     )
                );
            }
        }

        base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

**Sample usage:**

```
<local:SquareLayout>
    <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Green" 
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".1,.1,1,1" 
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />

    <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Blue" 
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,.2,.1" 
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />

    <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Red" 
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".9,.9,200,200" 
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />

    <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow" 
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="10,20,.3,.3" 
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional" />

    <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Silver" 
                    local:SquareLayout.IsSquare="false"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".9,.9,1,.1" 
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
</local:SquareLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow great explanation!! Thank you for the understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution involving a `Frame` with an `AbsoluteLayout` as a child.

`Frame` will ensure that the `AbsoluteLayout` is centered.

```xml
<Frame x:Name="absoluteSquareLayout" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="absoluteLayout">
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</Frame>
```

Then, in the code behind, the dimensions of the `AbsoluteLayout` is derived from the dimensions of the `Frame`:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    absoluteSquareLayout.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        var size = Math.Min(this.Width, this.Height);
        absoluteLayout.WidthRequest = size;
        absoluteLayout.HeightRequest = size;
    };
}
```